# How to clear the dataset rows based on the column headings in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dataset

Suppose i have a dataset which contains a table having columns with headings like A,B,C
 and i need to clear the all contents of B column only. How can i do that?

At present what i done is that, first i removed the column B

```
Dataset.Tables[0].Columns.Remove(B);
```

Then added back

```
Dataset.Tables[0].Columns.Add(B);
```

But the column index will changed if do the above method.Is there any other efficient way to do the same ...?

Comment: What means "clear", do you want to aply the default values of the type or an empty string(if it's a string column)?

Comment: clearing means all the contents of that column should be empty

Comment: Note that a `DataColumn` can have different types than string. What is an "empty `DateTime` or `int`?

Comment: i really meant for string datatype

Comment: i have edited my answer to show a generic way to assign any type's default value, which could be used in a method `ClearTableColumn`. In your case it's not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a loop:

```
foreach(DataRow row in Dataset.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    row.SetField("B", ""); // or whatever you want to assign
}
```

You could also remove the column, add it again and use `SetOrdinal` to get the same position:

```
int ordinal = Dataset.Tables[0].Columns["B"].Ordinal;
Dataset.Tables[0].Columns.Remove("B");
DataColumn bCol = Dataset.Tables[0].Columns.Add("B");
bCol.SetOrdinal(ordinal);
```

The latter is not more efficient than the plain loop since it [also uses a loop behind the scenes](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataColumnCollection.cs,fdb021b4f011e7b8,references).

If you need a generic approach to assign an "empty" value which means the default value for the given column type you could use this approach:

```
Type colType = Dataset.Tables[0].Columns["B"].DataType;
object defaultValue = colType.IsValueType ?  Activator.CreateInstance(bType) : null;
foreach (DataRow row in Dataset.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    row.SetField("B", defaultValue); 
}
```

Comment: if it contains no of rows suppose 1lac or more it will effect the code performance speed right

Comment: @Athul: have a look at my answer, i have already edited it. How often do you want to recreate this table with 100000 rows? Why at all? Why can't you have the correct value in the first place?

Comment: @Athul: you can test it with a `System.Diagnostics.StopWatch`. But i guess that it's not more efficient since all fields mut be initialized anyway. The second approach just hides the loop the framework is using behind the scenes. **Edit** Confirmed, here is the relevant source which loops the table when you add a column: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataColumnCollection.cs,fdb021b4f011e7b8,references

Answer (score 2):

```
  dt.Columns.Remove("B");
    dt.Columns.Add("B").SetOrdinal(1);
```

Comment: How is it different to my second approach?